# JPGs downloaded from Facebook unrecognizable to Shotwell

Tags: shotwell, facebook, jpeg

For some reason, Shotwell is unable to import or view jpg files downloaded from Facebook. (I doubt that Facebook has much to do with the issue - just mentioning my specifics here).

I hit the download link under a photo on Facebook, choose to save the file, then once it has downloaded I move it from my downloads folder to my pictures folder. I double check that the name ends in .jpg - yet when I search for the file using Import From Folder in Shotwell, its name is watermarked, and therefore cannot be selected or imported. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the filename is watermarked is because you've selected the Import From *Folder* menu item.

When you import from Folder, all files in the folder that can be imported will be; you don't select individual files, you select a *folder*.

Try again, this time select your Pictures folder then click OK. All images in the Pictures folder that haven't already been imported will be.